# Copy contents of one file into other using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I have written following piece of code with an intention to copy contents of abc.txt into another file xyz.txt

but the statement `b_file.write(a_file.read())` doesn't seem to work as intended. If I replace a_file.read() with some string, it (the string) gets printed.

```
import locale
with open('/home/chirag/abc.txt','r', encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()) as a_file:
    print(a_file.read())
    print(a_file.closed)

    with open('/home/chirag/xyz.txt','w', encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()) as b_file:
        b_file.write(a_file.read())

    with open('/home/chirag/xyz.txt','r', encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()) as b_file:
        print(b_file.read())
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj).

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `a_file.read()` twice. The first time it reads the whole file, but that is lost with the attempt to do it again after opening `xyz.txt` -- so nothing gets written to that file. Try this to avoid the problem:

```
import locale
with open('/home/chirag/abc.txt','r',
          encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding()) as a_file:
    a_content = a_file.read()  # only do once
    print(a_content)
    # print(a_file.closed) # not really useful information

    with open('/home/chirag/xyz.txt','w',
              encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding()) as b_file:
        b_file.write(a_content)

    with open('/home/chirag/xyz.txt','r',
              encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding()) as b_file:
        print(b_file.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

To copy the contents of abc.txt to xyz.txt, you could use [`shutil.copyfile()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile):

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile("abc.txt", "xyz.txt")
```